# sort records from two databases

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

Here is my problem. I have two websites, website A and website B. Website A uses local database and website B is offering an API. I have to merge records from website A and B (API).

For example, a category (id = 10) on website A is merged with a category on website B (id = 20),

Now I need to merge records from local database and API. I can merge two arrays, but I need to sort records as well.

On website A I use queries to get records and from website B I use soap API.

What is the best way I can sort records by publish_date or title? keeping in mind there can be thousands of records from each database.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: What is stopping you sorting them after you have merged them?

Comment: Get the records from both sources and insert them into a new database/table with the columns you need. Then you can let MySQL do the sorting, which is what it's good at. You will need to standardize the way you input the data (convert all timestamps to MySQL `timestamp` with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`, etc.

Comment: update your code for more clarity

Comment: I can sort them with PHP, but there would be thousands of records from each database, let's say 5k from one database and 3k from other database. If I use PHP will it not be a very slow process?

Answer (score 0):

Sort it width PHP. This is only way to sort data from different types of sources.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: There will be thousands of records from each database, will it not make the process slow, secondly, I have to do pagination as well.